# TFS_Datawarehouse - report on Acceptance criteria

Tags: tfs, report

I am in the process of creating a TFS SSRS report that gives me the list of acceptance criteria for a user story. I can't seem to find the field in Workitem table, currentworkitem view.

Can anyone help me with this? Is it a reporting field available in TFS Warehouse data base or analysis services?

Thanks,
Aruna

Answer (score 0):

In my TFS server, we have a `tbl_Field` table in the Collection db that is associated with the `WorkItemLongTexts` table's **Words** field with the **Acceptance Criteria** (AC) and the **Descriptions**.

Here's the part of the query to identify them:

```
DECLARE @AC AS INT = (SELECT FieldId FROM Tfs_Collection.dbo.tbl_Field WHERE Name = 'Acceptance Criteria')
DECLARE @DESC AS INT = (SELECT FieldId FROM Tfs_Collection.dbo.tbl_Field WHERE Name = 'Description')

SELECT BACKLOG_SYSTEM_ID, AddedDate, Words,
    CASE FldId WHEN @AC THEN 'AC' WHEN @DESC THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'OTHER' END AS TEXT_TYPE, 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID, FldID ORDER BY AddedDate) AS ROW_NUM 
FROM Tfs_Collection.dbo.WorkItemLongTexts 
WHERE FldId IN (@AC, @DESC)
```

Unfortunately, I use a server that is a replication of the actual server so I don't know if any field names were changed or there are any custom items - **YMMV**.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Is it a good practice to use TFS Core database for reporting? I remember reading about not using TFS Core but the TFS Datawarehouse to create SSRS reports.

Comment: I am using some copy of the data - though I don't know if it's one that our DBAs directly created from the actual DB or a Datawarehouse version. I don't have access to see what the actual DB looks like.